# When is `.=` more efficient than `=`?

Tags: arrays, performance, julia, microbenchmark

Consider the following REPL lines using `BenchmarkTools`:

```
julia> N = 10^2; M = collect(reshape(1:N^2,N,N)); e = collect(1:N); # N=100
julia> @btime M[:,1] .= e; @btime M[:,1] = e;
  1.211 μs (6 allocations: 128 bytes)
  364.623 ns (1 allocation: 16 bytes)
julia> N = 10^3; M = collect(reshape(1:N^2,N,N)); e = collect(1:N); # N=1000
julia> @btime M[:,1] .= e; @btime M[:,1] = e;
  1.511 μs (6 allocations: 128 bytes)
  1.634 μs (1 allocation: 16 bytes)
julia> N = 10^4; M = collect(reshape(1:N^2,N,N)); e = collect(1:N); # N=10000
julia> @btime M[:,1] .= e; @btime M[:,1] = e;
  3.514 μs (6 allocations: 128 bytes)
  13.230 μs (1 allocation: 16 bytes)
```

It seems that `.=` is more efficient than `=`, but only for large N. I still do not understand very well what's happening under the hood and do not find explanations in the Julia documentation. When should I use one or the other?

Comment: `.=` is always preferred here, but you want `@btime $M[:,1] .= $e` to time it more accurately -- otherwise you are mostly seeing the effects of global scope.

Comment: @mcabbott, thanks for your answer. The problem was the benchmark and `.=` is always better. Don't you want to post it?